# Getting a 403 Forbidden Error while uploading a document using SharePoint 2013 REST API

Tags: rest, asp.net-core-mvc, sharepoint-2013, http-status-code-403

I am working on a task to generate an on demand spreadsheet/document and upload the generated document to SharePoint 2013 (on-prem) from .net core 2.0 application. I am using Epplus.core libraries to generate the spreadsheet. Using CSOM is not an option for me as I didn't find any nuget libraries which support .net core 2.0 framework so, I am trying to use SP REST API to upload the generated document.

Here's my sample code to upload a document to sp document library.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\test.xlsx"; //File to be uploaded
        string siteurl = "https://SpSite"; //site on which file needs to be uploaded (don't put  / at end)
        string documentlibrary = "DocumentLibrary"; //Document library where file needs to be uploaded
        bool filestatus = UploadUsingRest(siteurl, documentlibrary, filePath);
        if (filestatus)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File uploaded successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error uploading file");
        }
    }

    //Method to upload File
    public static bool UploadUsingRest(string siteurl, string libraryName, string filePath)
    {
        bool status = false;
        byte[] binary = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        string fname = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        string result = string.Empty;
        //Url to upload file
        string resourceUrl = siteurl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + libraryName + "')/Files/add(url='" + fname + "',overwrite=true)";
        HttpWebRequest wreq = HttpWebRequest.Create(resourceUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        wreq.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        //credential who has edit access on document library
        NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
        wreq.Credentials = credentials;
        //wreq.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
        //Get formdigest value from site
        string formDigest = GetFormDigestValue(siteurl, credentials);            
        wreq.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", formDigest);
        wreq.Method = "POST";
        wreq.Timeout = 1000000; //timeout should be large in order to upload file which are of large size
        wreq.Accept = "application/json; odata=verbose";
        wreq.ContentLength = binary.Length;
        try
        {
            using (System.IO.Stream requestStream = wreq.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(binary, 0, binary.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            WebResponse wresp = wreq.GetResponse();
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(wresp.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                status = true;
                return status;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return status;
            throw;
        }
    }

    //Method which return form digest value
    private static string GetFormDigestValue(string siteurl, NetworkCredential credentials)
    {
        string newFormDigest = "";
        HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(siteurl + "/_api/contextinfo");
        endpointRequest.Method = "POST";
        endpointRequest.ContentLength = 0;
        endpointRequest.Credentials = credentials;
        endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        //endpointRequest.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)";

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            WebResponse webResp = endpointRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream webStream = webResp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
            string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            var j = JObject.Parse(response);
            var jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
            foreach (var item in jObj["d"].Children())
            {
                newFormDigest = item.First()["FormDigestValue"].ToString();
            }
            responseReader.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return newFormDigest;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue.  The community will greatly appreciate any solutions found!